# Isso é um bug do Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

O código abaixo é uma demonstração do que estou tentando fazer: tenho um vetor (`todos`) no qual vão sendo adicionados elementos. O segundo vetor (`alguns`) também recebe novos elementos, e preciso saber se os elementos de `alguns` já são conhecidos, por estarem no vetor `todos`. Os elementos já conhecidos, que estão no vetor `todos`, são removidos do vetor `alguns`:

```
todos = ["b", "g", "c", "e", "d", "a", "h", "d"]
print("todos:", todos)
alguns = ["h", "c", "k", "a", "d", "j", "a"]
print("alguns:", alguns)
for letra in todos:
    if letra in alguns:
    print("remover letra:", letra, ", pois esta em alguns:", alguns)
    alguns.remove(letra)
print ("alguns apos limpeza:", alguns)
```

A saída da execução, na forma que o código está, é a seguinte:

```
todos: ['b', 'g', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'a', 'h', 'd']
alguns: ['h', 'c', 'k', 'a', 'd', 'j', 'a']
remover letra: c , pois esta em alguns: ['h', 'c', 'k', 'a', 'd', 'j', 'a']
remover letra: d , pois esta em alguns: ['h', 'k', 'a', 'd', 'j', 'a']
remover letra: a , pois esta em alguns: ['h', 'k', 'a', 'j', 'a']
remover letra: h , pois esta em alguns: ['h', 'k', 'j', 'a']
alguns apos limpeza: ['k', 'j', 'a']
```

Notem que o último elemento de `alguns` não foi removido, talvez por estar repetido, apesar de estar em `todos`. Se modificar o código para percorrer o vetor `alguns` e verificar se o elemento está em `todos`, e então retirá-lo, também não funciona:

```
todos = ["b", "g", "c", "e", "d", "a", "h", "d"]
print("todos:", todos)
alguns = ["h", "c", "k", "a", "d", "j", "a"]
print("alguns:", alguns)
for letra in alguns:
    if letra in todos:
    print("remover letra:", letra, ", pois esta em alguns:", alguns)
    alguns.remove(letra)
print ("alguns apos limpeza:", alguns)
```

Saída:

```
todos: ['b', 'g', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'a', 'h', 'd']
alguns: ['h', 'c', 'k', 'a', 'd', 'j', 'a']
remover letra: h , pois esta em alguns: ['h', 'c', 'k', 'a', 'd', 'j', 'a']
remover letra: a , pois esta em alguns: ['c', 'k', 'a', 'd', 'j', 'a']
remover letra: a , pois esta em alguns: ['c', 'k', 'd', 'j', 'a']
alguns apos limpeza: ['c', 'k', 'd', 'j']
```

Alguma sugestão do que posso fazer pra resolver? Pensei em ordenar os vetores, mas acho que não é uma opção, pelo tipo de elemento que estou utilizando nos vetores do código original.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: considere a possibilidade de usar conjuntos `set()`, vai funcionar melhor para o que você quer fazer

Comment: Vou pesquisar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isso é um bug do Python 3.6?

Não, dificilmente você iria achar um bug no Python com um código tão simples.

A questão aqui é falta de conhecimento sobre as funções nativas do python. Atente no que diz a [documentação sobre a função `remove` de uma lista](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> list.remove(x)
>
> Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

Traduzindo:

> list.remove(x)
>
> Remove o **primeiro elemento** da lista cujo valor é x. É um erro se não houver tal item

Repare que eu dei enfase no **primeiro elemento** pois é apenas o removido. Veja este exemplo simples que toca no problema:

```
alguns = ["h", "c", "k", "a", "d", "j", "a"]
alguns.remove("a")
print(alguns)  # ['h', 'c', 'k', 'd', 'j', 'a']
```

Apenas removeu o primeiro `a` como esperado, e por isso ainda sobra um `a` na lista.

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/hcucGs)

Não tem uma função tão direta como o `remove` para remover todas as ocorrencias, mas tem várias formas de o fazer. Tentando manter a ideia que tem nos *loops* pode por exemplo utilizar [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
todos = ["b", "g", "c", "e", "d", "a", "h", "d"]
alguns = ["h", "c", "k", "a", "d", "j", "a"]

for letra in todos:
    if letra in alguns:
        alguns = [x for x in alguns if x != letra]  # <-- aqui "remove" todas as ocorrencias
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/OGGx69)

No entanto melhor seria construir uma lista apenas com os elementos de `alguns` que não existem em todos:

```
nova = []
for letra in alguns:
    if letra not in todos and letra not in nova:
        nova.append(letra)
alguns = nova
```

Nesta solução adiciona cada letra à nova lista se não existir no `todos` nem na `nova` lista. Assim evita ter de criar várias listas várias vezes, que é o que é feito no primeiro exemplo.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/D1yVK1)

Comment: Sim, realmente é desconhecimento, estou começando com Python agora, e ainda não li a documentação. Na verdade, estou tentando uma outra solução: ao invés de usar vetores, usar objetos e a função `difference`. Provavelmente Vou ter de mudar todo o código pra isso. Seria algo assim:

    `todos = {"b", "g", "c", "e", "d", "a", "h", "d"}`
    `print("todos:", todos)`
    `alguns = {"h", "c", "k", "a", "d", "j", "a"}`
    `print("alguns:", alguns)`
    `alguns = alguns.difference(todos)`
    `print("alguns apos limpeza:", alguns)`

Caso fique inviável, vou usar a sua solução.

Obrigado!

Comment: Ficou inviável, justo pela pouca familiaridade com a linguagem. Usei a sua solução. Vlws!